# Installing git on Windows Server with PowerShell remoting

Tags: git, powershell, chocolatey

I'm using PowerShell remoting to connect to my Windows Server 2016 and I want to install git.

The best option I have found was by installing chocolatey (by using the PowerShell snippet from [here](https://chocolatey.org/install)). Then, I want use `choco install git -params '"/GitOnlyOnPath"'` to install git.

The problem is that after installing chocolatey when I open a new remoting session it's missing from the environment path. Running `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path').Split(';')` contains *C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin* in the original remote session, but not in the new one. Running `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ChocolateyInstall')` results in the same. Interestingly, when I connect to the server with remote desktop connection and run PowerShell both variables are present.

I thought this could have something to do with chocolatey loading something into the profile. So I tested for a profile script in my remote desktop connection but there is no file.

Is it even possible to get the correct environment variables from a remote session?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I’m just going to throw in a completely untested suggestion.

The `Find-Package` documentation from MS hints at using the Chocolatey repository as a package provider. So, you could try running

```
Install-Package git -ProviderName “Chocolatey” -ForceBootstrap
```

In theory you’d be prompted to add the package provider and then install git. Whether or not this would solve your path issue I don’t know, but since it’s a native option I’m hoping so. I’ve always had issues with paths and packages installed by chocolatey.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to solve the path issue. Does this really install git? On my system it only creates batch files in C:\Chocolatey\bin that start an installer.